# For most car insurers in USA / Canada who give discount for Winter tires, do "All Season tires" qualify?

Tags: tires, cold-weather, weather-dependent, insurance

My CRV has [Michelin Premier LTX](https://www.1010tires.com/Tires/Reviews/Michelin/Premier+LTX) "All Season" tires.

For most car insurers in USA / Canada who offer a discount on insurance premium when tires are changed seasonally with "Winter tires", do "All Season" tires qualify?

As several commenters suggested, I should contact individual insurers directly.  But I'm just wondering what's the average position among all insurers in North America, especially in regions with at least 3 months of below 0°C average daily temperature like Boston or Calgary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance or repair.  It's about insurance.

Comment: You will need to check with your insurance company to determine THEIR definition of "winter tires".

Comment: @jwh20 thanks. Is there an SE site more appropriate for these kinds of questions?  Isn't this covered under the `insurance` tag?

Comment: I would suggest calling your insurance agent. I am sure they will be happy to explain their policy coverage.

Comment: @Anonymous - there's an assumption that somewhere on SE there must be a home for every reasonable question, and that is incorrect.  Some questions are just unsuitable - this is a direct question between customer and insurer and of use limited to the group "customers of that insurer"

Comment: All season tyres are not winter tyres. They are a compromise. In winter they do not perform as well as true winter tyres, and in summer they do not perform as well as regular tyres. If they did, there would be no need to use different tyres in regions with extreme differences between summer and winter climate. And it's not because all season tyres are expensive: I have budget all season tyres on one vehicle.

Comment: @Criggie Understood.  Just in case the community still wants to consider this question, I have modified it to be a general North American question about *typical* insurance provider policy hopefully of interest to many.

Comment: Arguably, Calgary seems to be 7 months a year below 0°C (or at least often below +7°C, when, according to recommendations, the tires winter tires are supposed to be used).